# Why does this simple, nested DIV render differently in Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: html, css

This nested `div` renders differently in FireFox and Chrome. Chrome, with the result I am looking for. 
A `div` that can grow with content, inside of another `div` that has a padding of `20px`.

The effect should look like it has a `20px` bar above and below the nested `div` like this (in Chrome). 
http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/58xRJ/2/embedded/result/

The code I'm using:

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="dualContainer">
        <div class="dualBgBlock"></div>
        <div class="dualMiddle">
            <div class="dualContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
div.dualContainer {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    width:100%;
}
div.dualBgBlock {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    padding:20px;
}
div.dualMiddle {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.dualContent {
    background-color:#333;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}
```

Link to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/58xRJ/2/

So how can I get FireFox to render my code the way Chrome does?

Comment: It seems like the `margin: auto` on the `.dualBgBlock` behaves differently. In Chrome, it centers horizontally *and* vertically, but in Firefox it only centers horizontally (like `margin: 0 auto`). I'm not sure what's going on here, vertical centering in CSS has always been problematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Padding is in the wrong place.  Move it from `.dualBgBlock {}` to `.dualContainer {}`

### [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/J5GWZ/)

CSS:

```
div.dualContainer {
    padding:20px;
}

div.dualBgBlock {
    // No padding here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move your padding to `div.dualMiddle`, [see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/58xRJ/4/)

```
div.dualBgBlock {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
    padding:20px; //remove this line

}
div.dualMiddle {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;  //add this line
}
```